# Showing set $S=\{ (y_1,y_2)\geq (0,0) | f(x)>f(y)\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on non-negative real numbers and $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$. Now, I wish to show that for any $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}$, the set $S=\{ (y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}_{\geq 0}  |  f(x_1,x_2) > f(y_1,y_2) \}$ is open.

**Here is my attempt:**

Let $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}$. I need to find a $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset S$. However, I couldn't manage to find. I'm open to any help.
[image]

Comment: Is the function $f$ continuous?

Answer (score 1):

The distance of $(y_1, y_2)$ to the line $x+y=x_1+x_2$ is $\frac{|y_1+y_2-x_1-x_2|}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Hence we can pick $r=\frac{|y_1+y_2-x_1-x_2|}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{a_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ and $\{b_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ be strictly increasing sequences that converge to $x_1$ and $x_2$, respectively. Then, $\{f(a_n, b_n)\}^\infty_{n=1}$ is a sequence completely contained in $S$ that converges to
$f(x_1, x_2)$. But, $f(x_1, x_2)\not\in S$. Thus, $S$ doesn't contain all limit points and therefore is open.

Answer (score 1):

If you know topological defenition of continuousity, then it can be prooved bt one sentence. If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous function and $B\subseteq Y$ is open set, then $f^{-1}B$ is open set of $X$...

And your set $S$ is just $f^{-1}(-\infty,x_1+x_2)$. $f$ is multivariable polynomial function, so it is continuous. and open interval $(-\infty, x_1+x_2)$ is open set of $\mathbb R$.